# ASP.NET web application visitor counter

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ipv6, ipv4

I've got a simple web application which I need to keep track of visitors. Each visitor's information is stored in the following table:

VisitorsDetails:

```
| ID | ComputerName | VisitDate | CountryCode | Platform | Browser | BrowserVersion |
```

`[ComputerName]` is vistor's IP address.

The table contains ipv6 records which causes problems in calculating visitor's count or sometimes causes Token errors.

Is it wise to force visitors to use ipv4?
if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public string IpAddress()
{
string strIpAddress;
strIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (strIpAddress == null)
{
strIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
return strIpAddress;
}

foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
 { 
if (IPA.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
 { 
IP4Address = IPA.ToString(); 
break;
 } 
}
```

Please refer below links also:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102847/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx
http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.in/2010/09/aspnet-get-ipv4-address-even-if-user-is.html

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    Application["NoOfVisitors"] = 0;
}





void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    Application.Lock();
    Application["NoOfVisitors"] = (int)Application["NoOfVisitors"] + 1;
    Application.UnLock();
}

in .aspx page

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbluser" />
in .aspx.cs

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbluser.Text = Application["NoOfVisitors"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Nice, but major problem is ipv6

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        WebpageCounter.SaveVisitor(new WebpageVisitor()
        {
            VisitorIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress,
            VisitedOn = DateTime.Now
        });
    }
-------------
Below Code is for IP Address
string ipaddress;
ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
    ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: It is possible that HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR returns multiple values. how do I make sure i will get ipv4 only